# Screenshots for privileges page

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface, privileges-page

Most of the screenshots on privileges pages are outdated. Shouldn't they be replaced with screenshots of the new design?

---

## Example 1: [Set Bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties):

**Current Image**

[image: Image 1]

**Updated Image**

[image: Image 2]

---

## Example 2: [Create Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

**Current Image**

[image: Image 3]

**Updated Image**

[image: Image 4]

---

There are many other screenshots that are also outdated.

Comment: While we're at it *a lot* of the help center needs updated images.... maybe a CW post is needed

Comment: @angussidney it used to be that way actually - there was a single faq page, editable by high rep users, but it was all replaced with the (now not so new) help center. [archived page](http://web.archive.org/web/20110812133852/http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @ShadowWizard What I meant was that we should make a post here on meta, then SE can simply copy each entry when they get the time. However making it mod or high rep editable would also be a good idea...

Comment: Your second screenshot is a fairly pointless update; naturally, PHP will continue to agglomerate more and more synonyms over time, but that's pretty unimportant. (The color changes *might* be relevant, and I can imagine the "php jobs" bit as well, but those aren't nearly as significant as the bounty example.)

Comment: -1, the "Create Tag Synonyms" updated image should have a hand-drawn circle.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Actually, the second screenshot focuses on the change in style (colour and font) rather than the number of synonyms PHP has

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't agree with updating screenshots to match changes in data that are, by their very nature, dynamic counters that'll change with time. Shall we update screenshots of the users list every time anyone's rep changes? But for UI/caption changes, absolutely. This is a problem with the help pages in general: they have not been kept up-to-date very well.