# Updating screenshots in help center

Tags: feature-request, help-center, screenshot

Some screenshots in our help center have been outdated. For example, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

[image]

It's still using old site design. Nerds at http://mathoverflow.net may love it, but most other users don't. Please replace them with screenshots taken at current sites.

However, please keep those [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/338645)!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279258/screenshots-for-privileges-page

Comment: [Here you go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwOWr.png). :)